# how to fetch last three year data in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

is there a way to fetch last three year data from the hive table
my column has a data in this format (2018-07-01 00:00:00.0)
I have to fetch out last three years data

Comment: use filter clause... `date_sub` function might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spark.table("tableName").where(col("dt") >= date_sub(current_date(), 365 * 3) && col("dt") < current_date())
```

Comment: @sandeeprawat i suppose this is one-off task. use java.time.LocalDate minusYears  if you want exactly 3 years

Comment: that is the catch   date_sub work for day there could may way do that in java or use add_month..

Comment: Will this add_months/date_sub work if my format is in "yyyyMM"?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.sql.Date

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{months_between, col, lit}


def getNewNowCal = Calendar.getInstance()
val nowDate = new Date(getNewNowCal.getTimeInMillis)

yourDF
  .withColumn("now_date", lit(nowDate))
  .filter(months_between(col("now_date"), col("date_event") =< 3*12) 
          && col("date_event") < col("now_date"))
  //date_event (in your dataframe) is less than 3 years from today
```

Answer (score 1):

it would look like  we need to get data more than 3*12 month

```
spark.table("tableName").where(col("dt") >= add_months(current_date(),"MM-dd-yyyy"),-3*12)
```

use if truncate it to month .

```
spark.table("tableName").where(col("dt") >= date_trunc( "month" ,add_months(current_date(),"MM-dd-yyyy"),-3*12))
```

Comment: it will show me the result from 2017-01-21. I need the whole data starting from 2017-01-01

Comment: use date_trunc( "month", date) .. i have added code

Comment: Can you please let me know which package to import as date_trunc is unidentifed in spark

Comment: scala> a.select($"Sales_Month").where(($"Sales_Month") >= date_trunc( "month" ,(add_months(current_date(),-3*12)))
     | )
<console>:29: error: not found: value date_trunc

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-date-and-time-functions/